# Call function of every instance of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am developing a small game and need some help. To check for collisions I created a class `Block` to create different shoes of obstacles. Now I plan to use the `colliderect` method of `pygame` to check for collision.

Is there a way to call a method not only for one class instance (e.g. `block_1.check()` but calling it for every instance of class `Block`? For example: `Block.check()` so it checks for `block_1`, `block_2`, `..., etc`?

Comment: Put your objects in a container (e.g. a `list`), then iterate over the container, calling the method on every object in the container

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest option is to maintain a list of references to each instance as a static variable of the class.  You would append to the list when the object is created, and remove from it once it's destroyed.

For example:

```
class Block:

    # Static variable; accessible as Block.blocks
    blocks = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 1
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

        Block.blocks.append(self)

    def destroy(self):
        Block.blocks = [block for block in Block.blocks if block.id != self.id]
```

Comment: You can just use `self.blocks`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pygame, I would recommend that you make the block class a subclass of pygame's Sprite class (see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)). Then you can use sprite Groups (see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)) to simplify performing operations on the groups of sprite (like updating, drawing, collision checking as well as killing sprites).

Collision checking can be done with `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` (see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect)), `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()` (see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany)), or `pygame.sprite.groupcollide()` (see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide))

You can also use the sprite groups as iterator in for loops:

```
for enemy in enemy_sprite_group:
    do stuff with enemy sprites
```

That is not quite what you asked since it is not a way to 'Call function on every instance of a class' but it is in the spirit of what you were trying to do since you are really asking about which was collision detection on your game objects.